# Wine Black window issue

Tags: wine

I'm having issues with wine, It is a black window, sound works fine, this only happens on anything that is uses 3D/2D graphics.

I'm using a GMA 3100 graphics card, and have no clue why this is happening, It is rather annoying.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend checking out `winecfg`.

From your terminal, run:

1. `winecfg`
2. Go to Applications tab
3. Check out the Windows Version dropdown. For example, when mine is set to `Windows 7`, I get black boxes and weird stuff. Changing it to `Windows XP` fixes the black areas.

I think at one point in my particular HeidiSQL issue, there was mention of intel driver issue, so I think it's worth mentioning that could you have a specific piece of hardware causing the issue. This would of course make it hard to reproduce, but as such, I think it's worth experimenting with the `Windows Version` options in winecfg to see if you can circumvent it.

There are some other graphics-related settings as well, not many but some. Good luck.

Source: https://www.heidisql.com/forum.PHP?t=22183

Answer (score 0):

There might be the following issues present:

- You haven't installed the necessary drivers for your graphics card.
- You are trying to run a DX10 / DX11 application. Those aren't supported at the moment. ([Though there are people who reached limited success with them.](http://pigflygames.com/index.php/blog))
- You didn't install all the dll's needed by your application. You can use [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks) for that.

Comment: What do you mean by haven't installed the necessary drivers for my graphics card, Do you mean I have to download the windows driver and install it on wine? I'm not using DX10 :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem.

First the system was working fine, even on winehq with dx11 after an installation out of the box. Unfortunately I trashed the whole system by the installation of a weird application, which deinstalled plasma!

Now after a reinstall from scratch, which I thought, I did it exactly the same way, using the same graphics driver (Geforce RTX3060, proprietary), d3d is no more working on winehq. Sound is ok, so the game is running, but only a black window. I can close it with Alt-F4, so it doesn't hang. The terminal reports no error. I've tried many settings in winecfg, but without luck.

OpenGL and Vulkan is installed, even the 386-libs.

I've tried almost any settings in winecfg and winetricks, but without success.

I can't find any guide to get out of such problems.

I miss a possibility, to find out, where is the missed link between application and the graphics card. As long as such a tool doesn't exist, it looks hopeless, to identify the problem.