# iTunes in wine black screen on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, itunes

I installed wine and iTunes. When I run iTunes application starts but it is unusable since I only get black screen. See photo. What to do here?

[image: i]

Comment: It's probably picking up your (dark) theme. But everything seems to be there. How is it unusable? FYI, it's just a media player, you dozens of native apps that do the same and better, why are you installing it anyway? It doesn't work in Wine for connecting devices.

Comment: @Samo you always start with wineHQ to know if a soft will work under wine : https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31322 the answer here is ye....no.

Comment: I know this is old, but I ran into this problem too.  I found this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1063692 but haven't been able to confirm it yet, as I'm not in front of my workstation.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use iTunes version 12.9.3 and older (32bit). It does not work with newer versions of iTunes (thanks Apple).

I highly recommend using the installation procedure described [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SVgGX9x1hWZzyhEJs5_7UH1K5i7Cuz6B2iuIwm40VrQ).

Works great and there is no need for PlayOnLinux.

Comment: Welcome to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) and thanks for contributing! Could you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1177318/edit) your answer to include the basic steps from the link you posted, so that the answer will remain valid even if the link is removed or does not work anymore?

Comment: @No da-mi pace @user3140225  I've followed these steps. When doing the last step, i.e.  `env WINEPREFIX="/home/david/.wine32" wine /home/david/.wine32/drive_c/Program\ Files/iTunes/iTunes.exe` , a blank screen appears. Do you know what might be failing?

Comment: @Dave I'm sorry. I just edited the answer. I don't know much about iTunes in Wine. I would suggest that you post a question about your issue. Hopefully someone will be able to help you!

Comment: @Dave Did you use use iTunes version 12.9.3 and older the 32bit version? The newer versions give a black screen.
you can get it here:
https://www.filepuma.com/download/itunes_32bit_12.9.3-21404/download/

Comment: @Noda-mipace Thanks for your comment. I've repeated the process using the iTunes version in that link. Again, I've followed these steps. When doing the last step, i.e. env WINEPREFIX="/home/david/.wine32" wine /home/david/.wine32/drive_c/Program\ Files/iTunes/iTunes.exe , that blank screen appears again.

Comment: Hi this worked for me thank you! Note of caution, iTunes crashed each time i tried to get logged in. Finally, i ignored the crash dialogue tried logging in anyway. After a number of attempts I was able to download my iTunes library and authorize my Ubuntu machine to play them. In addition I can play playlists saved from my Apple music subscription. But I've been unable to browse the store or find new music (always crashes). Here's a google doc with screenshot of my experience and some more details: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uJFuJvmyRzqwIy5bVIdeByFfMjO81PHAMxxwZ_UviaU/edit?usp=sharing